# cannot login after create login and grant access to db by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to create login and grand access to my db. But when I run code in sql file and a can create new login, and login to sql server success:

```
Use DuLieuChuan
GO
CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH PASSWORD = '123456789', 
    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English], 
    CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, 
    CHECK_POLICY=ON;
GO
CREATE USER db_TestLogin FROM LOGIN TestLogin;
GO
ALTER LOGIN TestLogin ENABLE;
```

But I create a stored procedure with code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[addDBMSLogin]
( 
    @loginname nvarchar(100),
    @password nchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @safe_login varchar(200)
    DECLARE @safe_password varchar(200)
    SET @safe_login = replace(@loginname,'''', '''''')
    SET @safe_password = replace(@password,'''', '''''')

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @safe_login + 
                   ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @safe_password + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DuLieuChuan], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON ' +
               'CREATE USER ' + @safe_login + ' FROM LOGIN ' + @safe_login + ';'
    EXEC (@sql)

    EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = @safe_login, @rolename = N'sysadmin';

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @safe_login + ' ENABLE';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
END
```

After execute this procedure, I can also create a new loginname, but i cannot use this loginname to login to SQL Server with follow message:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to *****.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'test5'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
```

Can you help me why? This is my final exam :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to split query for login and user creation for two queries and exec them one by one

Comment: Thank Andy!
I am tried, but i still cannot login with loginname which created by stored procedure :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[addDBMSLogin]
( 
    @loginname nvarchar(100),
    @password nchar(100)
)
```

To

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[addDBMSLogin]
( 
    @loginname nvarchar(100),
    @password nvarchar(100)
)
```

Your password is being padded with spaces.

Comment: yeah! Thank you for support me. It`s very nice. I try and login success. :)